# Windows 7 Upgrading: "Windows was unable to create a required installation folder"

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, 64-bit, boot-camp

I have an office machine that's running a full OEM **Windows 7 Professional x64**, and I've been handed a full retail **Windows 7 Ultimate x64** DVD and key to upgrade the machine with. I had assumed that Microsoft would facilitate this process, instead I got the following error when I run setup.exe and clicked "Install Now":

`Error: 80070005 - Windows was unable to create a required installation folder`

I followed the instructions at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968003

This is all being done a **BootCamped Mac**.

But now I'm wondering if I've made a mistake by doing so.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What other issues are you having? Or is it 'just' refusing to upgrade?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It's "just" refusing to upgrade. It's essential that it does upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Apple is to blame (as usual). You're supposed to have to install the following utility to unmount the Apple partition while you upgrade.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3172

Comment: Are you running a support version of BootCamp and OS X?

Comment: Nice catch - this worked perfectly. I was experiencing the same issue while installing Win8 to a new partition, but this corrected the problem.

Comment: Worked for me! Required a restart then I could install.